# vue render does not work when return string

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, render

i'm using render with vue.js and iview, today when i use it, i find it doesn't work

```
{
  title: 'title1',
  key: 'order',
  render:(h, params) => params.index + 1
}
```

then I try to use it in another way, it works.

```
{
  title: 'title1',
  key: 'order',
  render:(h,params) => h('span', params.index + 1)
}
```

but the first way used to work days ago, i don't know why
how can i make the first way available?

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter in the `render` function `h` which is nothing but a function usually called `createElement` which contains information describing to Vue what kind of node it should render on the page.

This `createElement` takes 3 arguments:

1. The HTML tag name. This is required.
2. An object contains the attributes you pass in normal template. This is optional.
3. Children nodes as an array or a simple text node as a string. This is optional.

You did not return the `h` function ,since the first argument is required and not provided in your first snippet of code, it did not work.

Reference - [Render functions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html)

To make your first snippet of code to work you to return the `h` function with the 1st argument any tag name like you are doing in the second snippet.